# CS50 Pset2 Readability last part of the code won`t work

Tags: cs50, readability

I'm having trouble with the last part of the code for pset2 readability. 
It will grade ok.

But when `grade >= 16`, it does not print `Grade 16+`
And when `grade < 1`, it does not print `Before Grade 1`

This is the code

```
if (grade >= 0 || grade < 16)
{
    printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(grade));
}
else if (grade >= 16)
{
    printf("Grade 16+\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Before Grade 1\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (grade >= 0 || grade < 16) { printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(grade));
```

You shouldn't put || you should put &&

```
  if (grade >= 0 && grade < 16) { printf("Grade %i\n", (int) round(grade));
```